# Can I stop the low battery notification on M1 MacBook whenever it reaches 10%?

Tags: macos, battery, notifications

I use M1 MacBook Air but this machine keeps notifying me of the low battery status whenever my Mac reaches 10% of the available battery. I don't like to get notified, so would rather block it, but on the Notifications panel on the System Preferences, there are no battery-related settings.

Is it possible to disable it completely?

Or at least is it possible to make the badge disappear automatically? Right now it keeps being there, so I have to click the X button whenever it shows up. I use macOS 11.4.

Comment: Why do you want to run your battery below 10%?

Comment: @Gilby Why not? It is a state I can use the Mac in.

Comment: Frequently going very low will stress battery and  lead to shorter lifetime. If below 10% you really need to know about it and get it charged asap.